# How to conditionally render routes based on different screen sizes in React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to know how I can achieve something like this:

routes.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "chats",
        element: <ChatList />,
        children: [
          // {
          //   path: ":id",
          //   element: <ChatDetails />,
          // },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: "chats/:id",
        element: <ChatDetails />,
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        element: <Profile />,
      },
      ...
]);
```

I want to use this for screen sizes larger than 1024px

```
children: [
  {
    path: ":id",
    element: <ChatDetails />,
  },
],
```

and this for screens less than 1024px

```
{
  path: "chats/:id",
  element: <ChatDetails />,
},
```

I have found the workaround to this. I used react-responsive library

```js
const isBelowLargeScreens = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 1024 });
```

and then conditionally rendered the links like this.

```
{users.map((user) => (
  <NavLink
    key={user.userID}
    to={isBelowLargeScreens
      ? `/mchats/${user.userID}`
      : `/chats/${user.userID}`
    }
    className={({ isActive }) => isActive
      ? `text-rose-500 ${navlinkStyles}`
      : navlinkStyles
    }
  >
    {user.displayName}
  </NavLink>
))}
```

Comment: Do you already have the logic somewhere to compute the screen size in the UI code? See [mcve]. Are you basically just wanting to "conditionally render" the `ChatList` based on the screen size?

Comment: I'm creating a chat application which has quite similar UI to WhatsApp web. In WhatsApp web, the ui have chat list and the chat details together but in mobile, the only view is either the chat list or when we click a chat we get the chat details page. I found the workaround to this, thanks to your conditionally rendering suggestion. I renamed this route from ```path: "chats/:id",``` to ```path: "mchats/:id",``` to depict it's for mobile and then use media query in my chatList component to check if it's below large screens and then conditionally passed the route to the navlink component
thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the UI components, including the "use media query"? I think you're on the right track though, I don't recommend conditionally render routes.

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated the question. Please have a look. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I suggest not conditionally rendering the routes, and not defining "mobile only" routes, but to instead conditionally render the `ChatList` component.

Create a layout route that conditionally renders `ChatList` based on the media query. Note here however that I've inverted the media query, assuming you only want the chat list to be rendered on larger sized screens, keeping only chat details on smaller mobile views.

```
const ChatListLayout = () => {
  const isLargeScreen = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 1024 });

  return (
    <>
      {isLargeScreen && <ChatList />}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

Update the `"/chats"` route to render `ChatListLayout` instead.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "chats",
        element: <ChatListLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            path: ":id",
            element: <ChatDetails />
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        element: <Profile />
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]);
```

[image: Edit how-to-conditionally-render-routes-based-on-different-screen-sizes-in-react-rout]

Screen 1023px

[image: screen 1023px]

Screen 1024px

[image: screen 1024px]

It appears that this `react-responsive` library also exports a `MediaQuery` component that can accomplish the same thing.

Example:

```
import MediaQuery from "react-responsive";

const ChatListLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MediaQuery minWidth={1024}>
        <ChatList />
      </MediaQuery>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-conditionally-render-routes-based-on-different-screen-sizes-in-react-rout (forked)]